# Silently login to auth0 from react app with username and password

Tags: reactjs, auth0, change-password

I have a change password (auth0) feature, my change password flow is react app make a request to a backend service (as machine to machine app of auth0). Then that backend make a PATCH request to update password property of user. All of this is completed.

But when the password has changed. React app session with auth0 ends, user must be redirected to the auth0 provider and login again. But I don't want it, I would like to make a silently login from react app (with username and password provided) right after password changed success and renew the session (rewrite auth0 domain new cookies). How can I achieve this?

I appreciate any helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the password has been altered, you have to re-authenticate with a new session. Thanks!

https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/password-change

<sub>(Affiliation: I'm Community Lead at Auth0.)</sub>

Comment: Yes, I known it. But is there a way to re-authenticate from my client side app without redirect to the sign in form of auth0 domain?